# meteor deploy isn't updating the code on my app on meteor.com

Tags: meteor

I had been developing the app a couple weeks ago and went back to it to make a few changes and I see the changes on my local version but I can't get them to app.meteor.com

I found this blog post: http://docs.meteor.com/#deploying.  I have created my account, logged in from the command line and claimed the app. I am listed when I type "meteor authorized appname" from the terminal.

However, when I go to https://www.meteor.com/account-settings it says: "You haven't authorized any apps to access your developer account."

When I type "meteor deploy appname" everything looks fine on the command line but the site is not reflecting any changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the "Claiming legacy sites" section of [this blog post](https://www.meteor.com/blog/2014/02/25/meteor-developer-accounts):

> If you have existing apps deployed with meteor deploy, you'll be prompted to claim them with the new meteor claim command when you try to deploy them with the new Meteor release.
>
> Once you are logged in on the command line, use meteor claim  to associate these legacy apps with your new developer account. If the old app was password-protected, you'll be prompted for the site password one last time before you'll be able to claim the app. Once you've claimed it, you'll be able to deploy to it, run meteor mongo and meteor logs, and manage authorized users with meteor authorized, as long as you are logged in on the command line.

Make sure you are running the latest version of meteor by running `meteor update`, and the next deploy attempt should prompt you to claim the old app.